# Spring DevTools persistent session empty session map

Tags: spring-boot, session, devtools, persistent

I am trying to make Spring session persistence work but so far no luck.
So I start the app, do log in, change Java code to force restart and session is lost after that.

Enabled session persistence using `server.servlet.session.persistent=true`.
I see this property is picked up, and Tomcat is configured properly.

After some debugging I found out that the doUnload() method in org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager is called properly but the session map is empty!
This happens in https://github.com/Oreste-Luci/apache-tomcat-8.0.26-src/blob/05aeff976f6a75346c95cf6d3a9c8add8b9cb0bc/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardManager.java#L338.

Any idea why this is happening? I did log in so I expect session to be created...

Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE, Tomcat started at same version

Comment: Try setting `server.tomcat.basedir` in spring boot configuration file. Refer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2490

Comment: Yeah I saw this but this settings is only applied if there are some active sessions to be persisted. In my case, there are none (see code link).